# How do configure/use HTTP Public-Key-Pinning (HPKP) in asp.net MVC application on localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers

I've to configure HPKP on localhost I don't have idea how to configure or use it.
Please help me if you did it

Answer (score 1):

> Implementing HPKP in ASP.NET Core
>   An easy way to implement HPKP is to use my library which you can get on NuGet: [Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders)

Simply install it to your ASP.NET Core project, and then you can add HPKP headers to your app with a single function call.

Example Configure method in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
}
else
{
    app.UseHttpsEnforcement();
    app.UseHsts(new HstsOptions
    {
        Seconds = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        IncludeSubDomains = false,
        Preload = false
    });

    app.UseHpkp(hpkp =>
    {
        hpkp.UseMaxAgeSeconds(7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
            .AddSha256Pin("nrmpk4ZI3wbRBmUZIT5aKAgP0LlKHRgfA2Snjzeg9iY=")
            .SetReportOnly()
            .ReportViolationsTo("/hpkp-report");
    });
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "hpkp-report",
        template: "hpkp-report",
        defaults: new { controller = "Report", action = "Hpkp" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
   }
```

Comment: I am this error while installing NuGet: Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.
PM> Install-Package Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders -Version 2.7.0

Install-Package : Could not install package 'Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders 2.7.0'. You are trying to install this package 
into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content 
files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Please Kindly Check your NETFramework Version is this " .'.NETFramework,Version=v4.5' " If not than not compatible this nuget. please upgrade or set this in asp.net core project its works fine.